# Check if an input is numeric or not

Tags: apex, email2case

In our email to case functionality, we plan to introduce a feature via which the users will be able to input the Legacy Account Id which is numeric along with the Salesforce Account Id which is alphanumeric.

Is there any method available in Saleforce library that can indicate whether the data is a string or number ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  The Salesforce dev guide has a bunch of String methods for this kind of stuff.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Methods of interest are:

1. `isAlpha()`
2. `isAlphanumeric()`
3. `isNumeric()`

Answer (score 5):

The `String` class had `isNumeric()`, `isAlpha()` and a number of other methods for checking the contents of Strings added in Winter '13.

The documentation for these methods can be found here :

- [isNumeric](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_isNumeric.htm)
- [isAlpha](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_isAlpha.htm)
- [String Instance methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_instance_methods.htm)

> ## isNumeric()
>
> Returns `true` if the current String contains only Unicode digits; otherwise, returns `false`.
>
> ## isAlpha()
>
> Returns `true` if all characters in the current String are Unicode letters only; otherwise, returns `false`.

Example usage:

```
String num = '123';
System.debug(num.isNumeric()); // Writes TRUE to the debug log
```